# How can I plot the value in the table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pstricks, plot

This is my work so far.

[image: plot]

```
%% document class
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


%% packages
% -----   Preamble  ---------- %
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1.2cm]{geometry} % géométrie de la page.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % permet juste d’utiliser une nouvelle norme LATEX concernant le codage des caractères.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % permet de taper directement à l’écran, dans le fichier *.tex, les caractères accentués.
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % permettent d’obtenir des caractère mathématiques (de toute beauté!).
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pas-math}
%\usepackage{exsheets, tasks}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pas-stat}
%\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel} % permet de spécifier au compilateur que l’on désire taper son document en français.
\selectlanguage{french}%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ------ end command ---- >

\begin{document}    
%\begin{multicols*}{2}

\schemestart
\chemfig{2Cr_2O_7^{2-}}\+ \chemfig{16H_3O^+} \+ \chemfig{3C_2H_5OH} \arrow{->} \chemfig{4Cr^{3+}} \+ \chemfig{3CH_3COOH} \+ \chemfig{27H_2O}
\schemestop \\[2pt]

\begin{table}[h!]
    %   \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5cm}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{*{9}{|c}|} 
        \hline
        %       \diagbox[width=4cm]{$ y_i $}{$ x_i $}   
        t(\si{\minute}) & 5 &  10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 40 & 50    \\ \hline
        V$ _\text{B}$ \si{\milli\liter}  & 6.3 & 12  & 17 & 22 &  26.4  & 30.3 & 37.5 & 43.5  \\ \hline     
        C$ _\text{A}$ (\si{\milli\mole\per\liter})  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline                                                        
        C(\si{\milli\mole\per\liter})  &  &  &  &   &  &  &  &  \\ \hline                                                                                       
    \end{longtable} 
\end{table}


I already filled the table. Now, I want to plot the graph `C$= f(t)  $ (t in horizontal axes and C in vertical axes)` below. 
    \\[2pt]

This is the formula that allow me to fill that table.\\

     C = $ 5 - 0,67\text{C}_\text{A} $ \ ; \ with C and C$ _\text{A} $  in \si{\milli\mole\per\liter}.




%\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [tag:pgfplots]; and [tag:pgfplotstable] if you want to reuse the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that CA is simply 0.1*VG.

It should be noted that `create on use` can be used to create column CA, but you can't use this column then to create column C (at not until you use it elsewhere).  `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` will create a column immediately, but cannot use `create col/expr`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{%
T,VG
5,6.3
10,12
15,17
20,22
25,26.4
30,30.3
40,37.5
50,43.5
}\data
\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/C/.style={create col/expr={5-0.067*\thisrow{VG}}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={C},ylabel style={rotate=-90}]
  \addplot[no marks] table[x=T,y=C]\data;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: By nodes I assume you mean the marks along the line, as opposed to the axis labels (which are implemented as tikz nodes).

Comment: Yes, the marks.